# Typescript: is there a type map for arrays

Tags: typescript

Say I have a list of booleans:

```js
const a: boolean[] = [true, false, false];
```

Can I build a type conditional that fires only when at least one of the booleans is true?

---

I can do it for the case where they're all true:

```js
type BList = true[] | false[];

type AreAllTrue<T extends BList> = T[number] extends true ? true : false;

const a: BList = [true, true, true];

const b: AreAllTrue<typeof a> = true; // This compiles
const c: AreAllTrue<typeof a> = false; // This doesn't (as expected)

// type AnyAreTrue<???> = ???
```

But I need the list to have both true and false, not just a list full of one type of boolean.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a tuple type, like `const a: [true, true, false] = [true, true false]`? Because if the _type_ is `boolean[]`, TypeScript doesn't really know what's going on inside of it.

Comment: Or `const a = [true, true, false] as const`, but definitely nothing to do at compile time if you have `boolean[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
type AnyIsTrue<T extends boolean[]> = T extends false[] ? false : true

type _test0 = AnyIsTrue<[]>  // false
type _test1 = AnyIsTrue<[false]>  // false
type _test2 = AnyIsTrue<[false, true]>  // true
type _test3 = AnyIsTrue<[false, true, false]>  // true
```

Hopefully this makes sense: an array of booleans doesn't have any `true`s if and only if it's a subtype of `false[]`.

---

However, as I said in the comment, if the type of your variable is `boolean[]`, TypeScript can't say much about it. It doesn't know what values are in the array.

```
type _test4 = AnyIsTrue<boolean[]>  // true
```

Comment: You have a typo on `_test3` in the comment, the result is `true`, as it should be.

Comment: Or `type AnyIsTrue<T extends boolean[]> = T extends false[] ? never : T`.

Comment: You should probably emphasize that this will not work for a variable of type `boolean[]`.